# Query size of local memory accessible to subgroups in Vulkan

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, vulkan, compute-shader

Is there a way to know how much local memory every compute unit has access to? For example in OpenCL I could call

```
cl_ulong size;
clGetDeviceInfo(deviceID, CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong), &size, 0);
```

Vulkan should have something equivalent to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLSL compute shader abstraction's equivalent to OpenCL local memory is [shared memory](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_variables): memory accessible to all work items in a work group (defined by `shared`-qualified variables). As such, you may [query `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Limitations) to get the amount of shared memory.